# Prove correctness of unit test

Tags: unit-testing, proof, correctness

I'm creating a graph framework for learning purposes. I'm using a TDD approach, so I'm writing a lot of unit tests. However, I'm still figuring out how to prove the correctness of my unit tests

For example, I have this class (not including the implementation, and I have simplified it)

```
public class SimpleGraph(){
 //Returns true on success
 public boolean addEdge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2) { ... }

 //Returns true on sucess
 public boolean addVertex(Vertex v1) { ... }
}
```

I also have created this unit tests

```
@Test
public void SimpleGraph_addVertex_noSelfLoopsAllowed(){
 SimpleGraph g = new SimpleGraph();
 Vertex v1 = new Vertex('Vertex 1');
 actual = g.addVertex(v1);
 boolean expected = false;
 boolean actual = g.addEdge(v1,v1);
 Assert.assertEquals(expected,actual);
}
```

Okay, awesome it works. There is only one crux here, I have proved that the functions work for this case only. However, in my graph theory courses, all I'm doing is proving theorems mathematically (induction, contradiction etc. etc.).

So I was wondering is there a way I can prove my unit tests mathematically for correctness? So is there a good practice for this. So we're testing the unit for correctness, instead of testing it for one certain outcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Unit tests don't attempt to prove correctness in the general case. They should test *specific examples*. The idea is to pick enough representative examples that if there is an error it will probably be found by one or more of the tests, but you can't be sure to catch all errors this way. For example if you were unit testing an add function you might test some positive numbers, some negative, some large numbers and some small, but using this approach alone you'd be lucky to find the case where this implementation doesn't work:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 1234567 && b == 2461357) { return 42; }
    return a + b;
}
```

You would however be able to spot this error by combining unit testing and [code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage). However even with 100% code coverage there can be logical errors which didn't get caught by any tests.

It *is* possible to prove code for correctness. It is called [formal verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification), but it's not what unit tests are for. It's also  expensive to do for all but the most simple software so it is rarely done in practice.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. However you say unit tests are not for proving code for correctness. If they're not for that, then what are you testing for. 

If you unit test for specific cases, that are representative, there could still be cases that you haven't tested. So basically you have code that is not tested. I'd a unit test is not very useful if it's not testing properly.

Comment: @Timo Willemsen: *So basically you have code that is not tested.* You can use code coverage tools to make sure that each branch is tested at least once. Unit testing is good for having a high certainty that you code works correctly in most cases without the expense of a formal proof. *I'd a unit test is not very useful if it's not testing properly.* - It's not perfect, but it's a *lot* better than not unit testing.

Comment: @Timo: Ideally unit-tests should be written so that every branch of your code is run by at least one test. This is not as strong as proving correctness, but still very useful. As Donald Knuth once wrote: *Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it.*

Comment: Unit tests need not test specific examples. QuickCheck is a great example.

Answer (score 2):

[Probably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) [not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems). Unit tests approach the problem by exhaustive testing:

- You verify that your test works by writing the test before implementing the behavior.
- Then you see that the test fails.
- Then you implement the behavior to pass that test, *and only that test*. Never write code that is not needed to implement a test.

Comment: Haha congratulations! Thanks for the answer. I was wondering though, because I could create a test that would do some mathematical inductino on the class. So test correct outcome for n=1, assume n=m and then prove m+1. I can code this in my software. But is it something I'd want to do in my unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

Really, what you're proving is that *one case* of your algorithm is working, eg you're proving that a subset of your execution paths are valid. Testing will never help you prove correctness in the strict mathematical sense (except for very simple cases). In the general case, this is [impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). Testing is a pragmatic approach to this problem where we try to show representative cases are correct (boundary values, values somewhere in the middle, etc.) and hope that that works.

Still, some tools such as findbugs etc. manage to give you conservative proof of some properties of your code.

If you would like formal proof of your stuff, there's always [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/), [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) and similar languages, but that's a hell of a stretch from writing a unit test :)

One great, simple introduction to testing vs proofs is [Abstract Interpretation in a Nutshell](http://www.di.ens.fr/~cousot/AI/IntroAbsInt.html) Patrick Cousot.

Comment: Well, my units are mathematic entities. So I could do mathematical induction in my unit test, proving the correctness of the unit right?

Comment: That would be some sort of meta extrapolation where you convince yourself that the unit is correct by induction. Java won't be able to tell you that (See the introduction I just edited and posted).

Comment: As someone mentioned above, Cobertura or similar code coverage can tell you if all your branches/code paths are exercised by a set of tests, but it still won't *prove* the correctness of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There are tool for formally specifying how your code operates and even tools to proof that they work in that way, but they are far away from unit testing area.

Two examples from the Java world are [JML](http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/JML/) and [ESC/Java2](http://secure.ucd.ie/products/opensource/ESCJava2/)

NASA has [a whole department](http://shemesh.larc.nasa.gov/fm/) dedicated to [formal methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods).

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents. Look at it this way: you think you wrote a function that **does something**, but what you really did was writing a function that **you think it does something**. If you cannot write a mathematically proof of what the code does, you can as well treat the function as a [hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothesis); you cannot be sure it will be always correct, but at least it is [falsiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability).

And that's why we write unit testing (note: just other functions, prone to have bugs, *sigh*), to try to falsify the hypothesis finding counter-examples with which it does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for correctness properties of your code, you can, as already mentioned in previous posts, apply some *formal verification* tools. This is not an easy thing to do, but may still be doable. There are tools like the [KeY system](http://www.key-project.org) capable of proving first-order properties for Java code. KeY has some problems with things like generics, floats and parallelism, but works quite well for most concepts of the Java language. Moreover, you can [automatically create test cases with KeY](http://www.key-project.org/download/testgen.html) based on the proof tree.

If you are familiar with JML (this is not hard to learn, basically Java with a bit of logic), you could try out this approach. For *really critical parts of your systems*, verification might really be something to think about; for other parts of the code, testing some of the possible traces with unit testing might already be sufficient, for example to avoid regression problems.